# what is the difference between <!--ko--> binding and visible binding in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

ko `<!--ko-->` binding and data-bind="visible:sometext" binding

Both binding did the same operation and which one is efficient for use and which one is best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<!-- ko [binding] -->` allows you to bind to an [virtual element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html).

`data-bind="[binding]"` is a regular binding and can only be applied to actual elements.

The difference is that the first can be used without having to create an element:

```
<ul>
    <li class="heading">My heading</li>
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->
        <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Do note that not every binding handler can be applied to an virtual element:

> Custom bindings can work with virtual elements too, but to enable
>   this, you must explicitly tell Knockout that your binding understands
>   virtual elements, by using the ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings API.

Comment: Thank u sir first i think ko binding is only used for check the condition,now i got clear idea about these bindings...

Answer (score 6):

### Virtual elements   :

- Can't be use to change the style of the element, because there is no bound dom element.

e.g. :

```
<!-- ko visible: prop--><!-- /ko -->
```

- Are useful to control flow when you can't add an extra element :

e.g. :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <!-- ko if: cond -->
            <tr><td>Optionnal line </td></tr>
         <!-- /ko  -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Actual elements `data-bind` :

- Can be used to control flow (if, foreach, with) and to modify the element attributes (style, id, class, etc).