# use of 'static' in Virtual element in knockout with ifnot binding

Tags: knockout.js, binding, virtual, element

I was going through a piece of code of knockout and i found this line...

```
<!-- ko ifnot: static -->

//your code

<!-- ko --> "
```

i have learnt about virtual elements and the use of if and ifnot binding but i am not getting that what this line is doing.

Comment: Read this for more info : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html

Comment: This is a good explanation here in stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971150/what-is-the-difference-between-ko-binding-and-visible-binding-in-knockout

Comment: why did you down voted this question ? i have gone through all this documentation but there is nothing about what static is doing here ?

Comment: I know how virtual elements work but what is static doing here ?

Comment: Check what is 'static' in your view model bound to that element - it seems its a property in the VM

Comment: i cannot find any thing named static so i was confused did that means any thing else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your application open in Chrome, open the developer tools and select the comment element `<!-- ko ifnot: static -->`. Then run in the console, `ko.dataFor($0)`, which will give you the view model that's bound to that element. You should see `static` listed in the view model object.